# rdiscount enable parsing markdown within block html?

Tags: jekyll, octopress, jekyll-extensions, rdiscount

Is there any global option for rdiscount to enable parsing markdown in block html tags? And any way to use that option within Octopress/Jekyll? This is the option that Kramdown supports:

> parse_block_html Process kramdown syntax in block HTML tags If this
>   option is true, the kramdown parser processes the content of block
>   HTML tags as text containing block-level elements. Since this is not
>   wanted normally, the default is false. It is normally better to
>   selectively enable kramdown processing via the markdown attribute.
>
> Default: false

Unfortunately, Jekyll does not pass this kramdown flag to kramdown. I opened an issue on that: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1095

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no RDiscount option for this. All options are listed in the API docs here:
http://rdoc.info/github/davidfstr/rdiscount/RDiscount

Here is a workaround for Jekyll/Octopress. Consider the following example:

```
<div>
    I want this to be in *Markdown*!
</div>
```

You can use the `markdownify` tag in Jekyll to manually force a section to be in Markdown:

```
<div>
    {% capture m %}I want this to be in *Markdown*!{% endcapture %}
    {{ m | markdownify }}
</div>
```

Comment: That almost works. The problem is that the resulting between {{ }} and is placed in a paragraph block. Any way around that?

Comment: Try putting the ...{% endcapture %}{{ m | markdownify }} together, directly adjacent to each other. RDiscount may be getting confused by the blank line where the {% capture %} appears. Let me know if this works - I'll update the Answer if it does.